# doubt regarding basis of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

i am studying basis of a vector space .let vector space be $V$ and subset be $B$. in it the two condition stated were that $B$ is a maximal linearly independent set in $V$ and second condition was that $B$ is a minimal spanning set of $V$. my doubt being , aren't both conditions essentially same, is it possible to satisfy one condition and not satisfy the other .

Comment: The two conditions are indeed equivalent, it's not meant in the way that a set has to satisfy both of them to become a basis but that it's enough to satisfy one of them, the other one will follow.

Comment: so maximal independent set and minimal spanning set are indeed d same . thanks @fweth . i was just getting confused . it was those 'just in case' cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two conditions are equivalent.

If you have a linearly independent set that does not span then you can always add a vector from outside the span to that set and it will remain linearly independent.  So a maximal linearly independent set necessarily spans.

Conversely if you have a spanning set that's not linearly independent then you can write one vector as a linear combination of the others.  That then tells you that removing that vector from the set does not change the span.  So a minimal spanning set is necessarily linearly independent.